# BJT instead of FET

Tags: transistors

[image]I'm making a contact microphone circuit and they say to use a MPF 102 transistor. I was wondering is it ok to use a BJT (that's what I have on hand) instead of the FET. If so would I hook the circuit up differently with the BJT or would it be the same as the FET. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a great idea and that 3.3Megohm resistor gives you a hint why...

The FET has a very high input impedance, so that 3.3Megohm resistor defines the input impedance of the amplifier.

Designing a bipolar transistor stage with such a high input impedance is possible but not easy, and I believe you would need at least two transistors, possibly connected as a darlington.

The FET shown is a simpler solution; if you can't find the MPF102, there should be alternatives (2N5459 is probably suitable, I have used it in microphone applications)

Comment: So what your saying is that there should be two transistors instead of 1 connected as a darlington like this... Using the 2N5459 transistors  [link] (http://www.ischematics.com/webspicy/share/img41888105775740786513b.png#newwin) @BrianDrummond or that it's ok to change the transistor?

Comment: The 2N5459 is another JFET so if you can get it you can simply change the transistor. If you MUST use BJTs then a Darlington may be the easiest option. (There is no point attempting a Darlington connection with JFETs as in that schematic)

Answer (score 0):

You would need a different bias circuit to use a BJT. You'd also need at least 2 stages of gain to get from the high input input impedance to the 1.5k output impedance your circuit has.